# Multiplying real matrix with a complex vector using BLAS

Tags: c++, matrix-multiplication, blas

How can I use Blas to multiply a real matrix with a complex vector ? When I use functions like ccsrgemv() I get type mismatch errors?

```
error: argument of type "float *" is incompatible with parameter of type "std::complex<float> *"
```

Comment: For people voting to close: this is a real question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use two matrix-vector multiplications (A * (x + iy) = A * x + i A * y). More precisely, consider your complex vector as two entangled real vectors with stride 2. BLAS lets you do this.

**UPDATE**: actually, I did not notice that you were doing Sparse BLAS. For `dgemv` my trick works, but for `csrgemv` it doesn't. I'm afraid you have to maintain real and imaginary part separately.

Comment: If I were to multiply a transpose of a complex dense vector with a dense real matrix (q = c^T * A), I'd use `sgemm()`/`dgemm()` routine: `call SGEMM('N', 'N', 2, N, N, 1.0, c, 2, A, N, 0.0, q, 2)` (in Fortran).