# Complex matrix multiplies real matrix by BLAS

Tags: matrix, fortran, addition, complex-numbers, blas

Related question [Multiplying real matrix with a complex vector using BLAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7619492/multiplying-real-matrix-with-a-complex-vector-using-blas)

Suppose I aim at C = A*B, where A, B, C are real, complex, and complex matrices, respectively. A[i,j] * B[j,k] := (A[i,j] Re(B[j,k])), (A[i,j] Im(B[j,k])). Is there any available subroutine in BLAS?

I can think about split B into two real matrices for the real and imaginary part, do `dgemm` then combine, (combine should be faster than matrix multiplication, even directly using nested loops(?)) as suggested by [Multiplying real matrix with a complex vector using BLAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7619492/multiplying-real-matrix-with-a-complex-vector-using-blas)

I don't know if there is a direct option in BLAS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no routine in standard BLAS that multiplies real and complex matrices together to produce a complex result.